# rspec expect to change record value after create it through post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have this piece of example to create a new record through `post` which is passed

```
describe 'POST create' do
  let(:schedule_child) { FactoryGirl.create(:schedule_child) }
  let(:post_queue) { post :create, schedule_child_id: schedule_child.id, format: :js }

  it { expect{post_queue}.to change(PatientQueue, :count).by(1) }
end
```

And I have one attribute, `PatientQueue.queue_number`, which will be increased by 1 every time a new record is added. Now I'd like to see if this attributes has changed.

```
it { expect{post_queue}.to change(PatientQueue, :queue_number).by(1) }
```

But here is what I got

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `queue_number' for #<Class:0x0000000849e780>
```

How should I write it properly?

**== UPDATE ==**

model `PatientQueue`

```
class PatientQueue < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Validations
  validates :patient, :schedule_child, presence: true
  validate :is_not_exist

  # Relations
  belongs_to :schedule_child
  belongs_to :patient

  before_create :insert_queue_number

  def is_exist?
    PatientQueue.find_by_schedule_child_id_and_patient_id(schedule_child_id, patient_id).present?
  end

  private
    def insert_queue_number
      last_id = PatientQueue.where("schedule_child_id = ?", self.schedule_child_id).count
      self.queue_number = last_id + 1
    end

    def is_not_exist
      errors.add(:schedule_child, :is_exist) if is_exist?
    end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

`PatientQueue` is an activerecord class, which has a method `count`

`post_queue` is an instance of the class and has the method `queue_number`

the class does not have the same methods as the instance, so you might write your test like `change(post_queue, :queue_number).by(1)`

However, the test is a little hard to follow, can you show us your data model relationships? if a `PatientQueue` has_many `schedule_child`, maybe you just want to use rails cache_counter? http://www.elegantruby.com/Tutorials/2013/01/25/adding-a-counter-cache-for-fun-and-profit/

Comment: Hi house9, I've added model `PatientQueue` and yes it has_many `ScheduleChild`. And I've tried to use `change(post_queue, :queue_number).by(1)` and got same error. I'm not quite sure how to implement cache_counter on my case as the new record is added by users which will be counted on `queue_number`